Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification. For Vite Application
When building my Vite application I'm getting an error that some chunks are larger than 500 kB.
After analyzing the visualizer I believe the problem is coming from the Three.js package in the node_modules folder. How do I split this chunk into smaller chunks?
Visualizer:
Visualizer
Error:
Error
My vite.config.ts file:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";
import { chunkSplitPlugin } from "vite-plugin-chunk-split";
import { visualizer } from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), visualizer({ open: true })],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return id
              .toString()
              .split("node_modules/")[1]
              .split("/")[0]
              .toString();
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
});


